# How to unit test firebase blocking functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, unit-testing, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am testing firebase blocking functions by `firebase-functions-test`, But the there is no overload on `wrap` function

Production code:

```
export const beforeSignIn = auth.user().beforeSignIn(async (user, context) => {
  if (user.phoneNumber == undefined) {
    throw new HttpsError(
        "permission-denied", "Invalid phone number");
  }
  return;
});
```

Test code:

```
const wrapped = wrap(beforeSignIn);
```

Error says:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(cloudFunction: HttpsFunction & Runnable<unknown>): WrappedFunction<unknown, HttpsFunction & Runnable<unknown>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'BlockingFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpsFunction & Runnable<unknown>'.
      Property 'run' is missing in type 'BlockingFunction' but required in type 'Runnable<unknown>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(cloudFunction: CloudFunction<unknown>): WrappedScheduledFunction | WrappedFunction<unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'BlockingFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CloudFunction<unknown>'.
      Property 'run' is missing in type 'BlockingFunction' but required in type 'CloudFunction<unknown>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(cloudFunction: CloudFunction<CloudEvent<unknown>>): WrappedV2Function<CloudEvent<unknown>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'BlockingFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CloudFunction<CloudEvent<unknown>>'.
      Property 'run' is missing in type 'BlockingFunction' but required in type 'CloudFunction<CloudEvent<unknown>>'.t
```

The `wrap` function doesn't accept type `BlockingFunction`, And how to test it by use `firebase-functions-test`?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect (that causes the compiler error you're showing). It'll be much easier to improve or correct what you have rather than trying to guess.

Comment: This sounds like it might be feature request to file on [firebase-functions-test](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test). Blocking functions are somewhat new, and the test lib maybe just hasn't moved forward to include them.